# Sum values between a colored range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to sum a range of values between a two cells with the same interior color. The output should be directed to a cell. The objective is for the user to define the starting cell and the cell for the output and the function should run until it changes column or finds a cell with the same interior function.

This is what I've done, but It gets #Value error every time. Notice I haven't added the rule to when the column shifts to stop the calculation, and my sum is probably the likely cause of the error , but I'm not sure.

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range, valx As Range) As Long

Dim datax As Range
Dim xcolor As Long


xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
valx = 0

For Each datax In range_data

    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        Exit For
    End If

    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex <> xcolor Then
        valx = datax.Value

    End If

Next datax

End Function
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get sum of cells values between colored cells you can use something like this:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range)
Dim datax As Range, CountVal, x%
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.Color = criteria.Interior.Color Then
       x = x + 1
    End If
    If datax.Interior.Color <> criteria.Interior.Color And x = 1 Then
        CountVal = CountVal + datax.Value
    End If
Next datax
CountCcolor = CountVal
End Function
```

*output*

[image]

to get count of cells between colored cells you can use this:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range)
Dim datax As Range, CountVal, x%
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.Color = criteria.Interior.Color Then
       x = x + 1
    End If
    If datax.Interior.Color <> criteria.Interior.Color And x = 1 Then
        CountVal = CountVal + 1
    End If
Next datax
CountCcolor = CountVal
End Function
```

*output*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not assigning a return value for your function:

eg.

```
'Not exactly sure what you want to return but this 
'is how you return a value from a function before you exit

'Assign return value to function name
CountCcolor = valx
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your requirements, but this is what I came up with:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sumColor(dataRng As Range, criteriaRng As Range, sumRng As Range)
    Dim xFound As Variant, xData As Range, xColor As Long, sumData As Long, lr As Long
    Dim fr As Long, fc As Long, foundRng As Range, inProgress As Boolean

    xColor = criteriaRng.Interior.ColorIndex
    sumData = 0
    lr = dataRng.Rows.Count
    For Each xData In dataRng   'For Each cell in 2D range, it traverse row by row
        With xData
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = xColor Then   'found first cell
                fr = .Row         'get its row
                fc = .Column      'and col
                sumData = xData.Value2  'capture its value

                With dataRng            'rest of the column bellow first found
                    Set foundRng = .Range(.Cells(fr + 1, fc), .Cells(lr, fc))
                End With

                For Each xFound In foundRng 'iterate to end of column
                    inProgress = xFound.Interior.ColorIndex = xColor
                    If inProgress Then
                        sumData = sumData + xFound.Value2
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If Not inProgress Then Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next
    sumRng.Value2 = sumData
    If sumData > 0 Then sumRng.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "(Col " & xData.Column & ")"
End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image: SumColor]

This function is in Sheet1 module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub x()
    With Me
        sumColor .UsedRange, .Range("B8"), .Range("D8")
        sumColor .UsedRange, .Range("B9"), .Range("D9")
        sumColor .UsedRange, .Range("B10"), .Range("D10")
        sumColor .UsedRange, .Range("B11"), .Range("D11")
    End With
End Sub
```